# Accessing fields in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

In my JSON object I am trying to access the "name" field within "pos"

I have tried obj.tokens.pos.parent;
             obj[0].pos.parent;

How can I access the parent field of this object?

the object looks like

```
[
 {
  "tokens": [
  {
   "text": "call",
   "normalised": "call",
   "end": true,
   "start": true,
   "pos": {
    "name": "infinitive verb",
    "example": "eat",
    "parent": "verb",
    "tense": "present",
    "tag": "VBP"
  },
  "pos_reason": "lexicon",
  "analysis": {
   "word": "call",
   "next": null,
   "last": null,
   "form": "infinitive",
   "tense": "present",
    "which": {
     "name": "infinitive verb",
     "example": "eat",
     "parent": "verb",
     "tense": "present",
     "tag": "VBP"
  },
  "negative": false
 }
 }
 ]
}
]
```

Comment: Can you show what you've done?

Comment: Do you want `tokens[0].pos.name` or `tokens[0].pos.parent`?

Comment: console.log(gotIt[0].tokens[0].pos.parent); When I print this out I get the correct value but I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Also please state clear next time what exactly do you want. You started off by mentioning "name" field then you are mentioning that you are trying to get the "parent" field. Anyways, you know the syntax now to access any .. :)

Comment: yeah sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Here the result is in array format so you need to access array element like obj[0]

```
obj[0].tokens[0].pos.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `obj[0].tokens[0].pos.name`

Comment: Thanks! I was just using the incorrect syntax!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but you can try this

```
obj[0]["tokens"][0]["pos"]["name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

`obj[0].tokens[0].pos.name`

Comment: Are you sure? You simple do this for example: alert(obj[0].tokens[0].pos.parent);That worked for me. Assuming that you made var obj = [ .... all that you have up there.

Comment: Actually that works. but the problem now is that I have multiple objects within tokens and I am trying to access each field by doing alert(obj[0].tokens[i].pos.parent) in a for loop but I only get the value from the first object

Comment: OK, could I see that for loop definition?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){ console.log(obj[0].tokens[i].pos.parent)}  I think my condition is probably wrong.

Comment: OK, this will only loop 1 time, if you only have 1 object. "i < obj.length" ..... Understand? It would have to be "i < obj[0].tokens.length; ..."